# Clarification regarding definition of structure sheaf in spec

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

In Hartshorne's algebraic geometry,sections for a open set U in spec A is defined as $s:U\to$$\bigsqcup_{p} A_{p}$ such that $s(p)\in A_{p}$.

It is also mentioned there for every p in U there is an open neighbourhood V of p contained in U such that $\forall q$$\in V$, s(q)=a/f where $f\notin$$q$.

Now my question is why the second condition is mentioned at all?  Because from the first condition we know $s(q)$$\in A_{q}$ and the elements of localization of A at q look like of the form a\f so the second condition seems redundant.

Also how s is similar to regular function at a point in variety.In variety it is represented locally as quotient of two polynomials but here it is merely quotient of two elements of A?

Comment: The second part you mention is actually a condition required of the structure sheaf. We know that $s(q)=a/f$ where $f \not\in q$ for all $q \in Spec(A)$, but we don't know that $s$ is constant on some neighborhood of $q$ without requiring it.

Comment: I think your confusion is in the quantifiers.  There is a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ and $a,f \in A$ such that for each $q \in V$, $s(q) = a/f$.  Note that the $a$ and $f$ are independent of $q$: we have *the same* $a$ and $f$ for all $q \in V$.  If we only knew $s(q) \in A_q$, then we would have $s(q) = a_q/f_q$, i.e., the $a$ and $f$ could depend on $q$.

Comment: So that means s is basically locally constant?

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely because you are implicitly dealing with the sheafification of the obvious presheaf. Look back at the process of sheafification from $II.1.2$. About the second question, perhaps read $II.1.0.1$.

[See this excellent answer.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/80560)